# How to import dependency/npm from .net core view?

Tags: c#, npm, .net-core, razor

I have a .net core project with the following `package.json`

```
"dependencies": {
  "slippi-lab": "https://github.com/cnkeats/slippi-lab.git"
}
```

Right clicking and selecting `Restore Packages` adds it to the `Dependencies` in my project:

[image]

How can I import or otherwise access the package from a view (`.cshtml`)?

Comment: Ultimately, it would be exactly the same as a standard html file.

Comment: That only imports from wwwroot as far as I can tell.